# Cut vector string at specific location from arguments

Tags: c++, string, vector, visual-studio-2017, command-line-arguments

we just started with c++ and I am stuck at an homework problem. Hope someone can give me a specific help here ..

Following situation: We are parsing values through arguments to our programm and the definition of the first parameter "argv[0]" holds the name of the program as everybody knows. But I just need the **"printParametersToFile.exe" from the argv[0] (C:\Users\Alex\Documents\visualstudio-workspace\OOP\OOP19_01\Debug\printParametersToFile.exe)** ... Here is my current try:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
std::vector<std::string> myArray; 
std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
std::string searchKey = ".exe";
std::string programmName;

// populate the Array
for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) 
    myArray.push_back(argv[i]);

for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {       
        ///z.B.: C:\Users\Alex\Documents\visualstudio-workspace\OOP\OOP19_01\Debug\printParametersToFile.exe
        std::cout << "Arguments = " << argc-1 << "\n";  
        it = std::find(myArray.begin(), myArray.end(), searchKey);

        programmName = ... 

        std::cout << "Programmname:\t" << programmName << std::endl;    /// Alternatively, the endl manipulator can also be used to break lines.

    }
    else
        std::cout << "Argument" << i << " :\t" << myArray[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Unfortunately my iterator variable is always NULL, does somebody here have a good solution for me here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *But I just need the "printParametersToFile.exe" from the argv[0]* -- Your question really has nothing to do with command-line arguments.  It is that you have a string that represents a full path, and you want the file name part of the string.  There are many solutions to that here -- just do a search and you will find them.

Comment: Ok the "Execution"-Path does not count as command-line argument ... You are true. 
Found a nice workaround here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/

Comment: **it = std::find(myArray.begin(), myArray.end(), searchKey);** searchKey=“.exe”, The third parameter needs to be the same as the string, so that the element will be found. If it's only part of the complete content, the function won't work properly, so it return NULL.